# Custom SQL Query Overrides All Other Report Data in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have written a custom sql query to get some specific data I need to use in my report. I added it through database expert and when I try to insert one of the columns from the custom query it replaces all of my other data and just pulls in the data from the query. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening or help me find a way where I can use all the data I need? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

database expert works based on the templates available in crystal report. this can not be undone once you execute them. I'd prefer to use manual instead of using it except your report designs similar to the templates provided.

Comment: Could I just include all the data I had in the report prior to inserting it inside the custom query? What would recommend from a manual perspective?

Comment: yes, sure. I usually browse the database and link it. then find the template that suits to my report concept. if it doesn't exits, I design manually and drag the columns into the report to design it. that's all.